# How should I approach a full stack Website, DO i host front end and backend on different ports?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, frontend, backend

Lets say i've got my frotend all done and ready to deploy, should i keep it on a port by it'self then use get request to make calls to an api / backend server port.

Should i Host my Backend in SpringBoot in one port or do i keep my front end with my springboot app and just host it on one port like 8080

if i were to host the front end ill host everything from html/css/ - to its framework on port 80 then host my backend springboot application on 8080 is that something good to do? or should i host them all together please help me clrarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How have you developed the frontend? As in, what technologies/frameworks have you used to implement the front-end / presentation layer of your website?

Since you've mentioned keeping it with spring boot you might have used something like thymeleaf or JSF

Generally, these are server-side template engines with the purpose of generating dynamic html content, not to serve as the full-fledge front end for your application

You could consider using js frameworks such as Angular/React/Vue to use as front-end (and yes - deployed on a different port) and spring boot for rest api.

Comment: I like your answer, from what im reading from you since u say "full feldge" so everything from react and css framework host them together on one port, then keep my dynamic pages on springboot on another port? like when i need it to be generated ill just simply make an api call that returns those pages?

Comment: How will you return the pages from an api call?

If it's a small scale application you don't need to separate out front-end and backend. the single spring boot app served on one port will handle your website's UI as well as business logic. 

If you want to separate out front end and backend a React/Angular/Vue app which only fetches data from Spring boot Rest API will be better than another spring boot app which sends api calls and does nothing other than render the UI

Comment: Thanks man that really clears things up